# Set an alert when all boxes are closed or collapsed in shinydashboardPlus

Tags: javascript, jquery, shiny, box, shinydashboardplus

I have a shinydashboard with 10 boxes, and which can be closed or collapsed. All the box id starts with "box". I was trying set an alert button when all boxes are closed or collapsed.

Below is the code of the dashboard:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboardPlus)

box_create <- function(i){
  shinydashboardPlus::box(tags$p(paste0("Box",i)), 
                          id = paste0("box", i), 
                          closable = TRUE,
                          collapsible = TRUE)
}

all_box <- purrr::map(1:10, ~box_create(.x))

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    all_box
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I have noticed on pressing close or collapse button shiny sets the display = 'none' for that box.
[image: inspect Box1]

So is it possible to extract all styles associated with the id which starts with 'box' and check if all the style property sets as 'none' using jQuery?

Comment: Thanks for the valuable inputs. Is it possible to do the same using jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Using shinydashboardPlus's dev version you can access the box state via it's `id` (pattern: `input$mybox$collapsed`).

Please see this [related article](https://rinterface.github.io/shinydashboardPlus/articles/improved-boxes.html).

Install it via `devtools::install_github("RinteRface/shinydashboardPlus")`

```
library(shiny)
library(tools)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)

box_ids <- paste0("box", 1:10)

box_create <- function(box_id){
  shinydashboardPlus::box(tags$p(toTitleCase(box_id)), 
                          id = box_id, 
                          closable = TRUE,
                          collapsible = TRUE)
}

all_boxes <- lapply(box_ids, box_create)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    all_boxes
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observe({
    if(all(sapply(box_ids, function(box_id){input[[box_id]]$collapsed}))){
      showModal(modalDialog("All boxes are collapsed!"))
    }
  })

  # observe({
  #   print(paste("Is box1 collapsed?", input$box1$collapsed))
  # })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: result]

Answer (score 0):

I thought you wanted a button when all were collapsed **OR** all were closed. Here is a solution for that.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)

box_create <- function(i){
  shinydashboardPlus::box(tags$p(paste0("Box",i)), 
                          id = paste0("box", i), 
                          closable = TRUE,
                          collapsible = TRUE)
}

all_box <- purrr::map(1:10, ~box_create(.x))

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    all_box,
    div(id = "alert_button")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observe({
    boxes <- paste0("box", 1:10)
    visible_status <- sapply(boxes, \(x) input[[x]]$visible)
    collapsed_status <- sapply(boxes, \(x) input[[x]]$collapsed)
    if (!any(visible_status) || all(collapsed_status)) {
      insertUI(
        selector = "#alert_button",
        ui = div(id = "added", actionButton("btn","all hidden OR all collapsed"))
      )
    } else {
      removeUI(selector = "#added")
    }
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```